# specific Laravel versions are not compatible with composer and artisan

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I use wamp to install Laravel 5 projects.
In versions of Laravel 5.1.11 and higher doesn't create the project with vendor and has problem with php artisan command.

When I install 5.1.0 version everything is fine.
What issues can have the other versions?

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Also, there'a a guide on [upgrading to Laravel 5.1.11](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11) in the documentation.

Comment: c:\wamp64\www\test2>php artisan

Warning: require(C:\wamp64\www\test2/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\test2\artisan on line
16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\test2/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\test2\art
isan on line 16

and the second error:
It does find the Illuminate\Foundation\Application

Comment: How are you installing Laravel? Using `laravel new AppName` or by using `composer create-project`?

Comment: I tryed both. Recently I used composer.

Comment: Run `composer clear-cache` and then try installing again.

Comment: nothing the same errors ... I tryed also to create a new one but the same...

Comment: I'm assuming that although you get an error, the new Laravel app directory is still created. If that's the case, just go into that directory and run `composer install`.

Comment: The same errors: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\test3\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'